# E262: error reading cscope connection 0

Tags: connection, cscope

I am using screens for coding using `vim` and `cscope`. when I leave the code for about 5 min (I mean go out for coffee etc) and start again. I can't use `cscope` again. I will get errors like:

- `E262: error reading cscope connection 0`
- `E257: cstag: tag not found`

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
:cs kill 0
:cs add cscope.out
```

For more help information, use

```
:help cs
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the changes permanently, you can add those two cs commands in *~/.vimrc* text file provided the cscope's default editor is vim.

To set default cscope editor, add the following line in *~/.bashrc*

**export CSCOPE_EDITOR=vim**